# LaTeX in Python

Tags: python, math, latex

I need to implement this latex function in Python without using any external libraries:

`R\left(A,\ B\right)=\sum_{n=1}^B\operatorname{mod}\left(A,n\right)`

What is the most efficient way of going about this?
BTW You can copy paste it into desmos.com in order to visualize it.

Comment: What do you mean implement.  Like parse it given that as input? Or just the equivalent function?

Comment: I meant the equivalent function, but it would also be great to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to implement that function, you can use a list comprehension and `sum()`:

```
def sum_mod(A, B):
  return sum(A % n for n in range(1, B+1))

print(sum_mod(7, 15))
```

Output:

```
64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This thought me a very useful python feature I never knew existed. I just have one more problem - When using very big numbers, I get a memory error because the arrays are too large.

Comment: A is about 10 million and b is about the same